# Adding two outlets mid circuit

Tags: electrical

I need to replace a 110v wall outlet in the middle of a circuit.  In addition I need to add an additional outlet in the same box (I've removed the single outlet box and replaced it with a double) and finally -- using this same circuit -- I need to add a single outlet a short distance away. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What wiring method are you using for this? NM? Armored cable? Conduit? Surface raceway?  Also, is this a finished or an unfinished space?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- "outlet" refers to a typical dual-receptacle (because otherwise this wouldn't make sense - replace a single *receptacle* with a dual *receptacle* doesn't require putting in a bigger box)
- Typical (i.e., not Chicago) NM (Romex) wiring

this is very straightforward:

- Disconnect the existing receptacle
- Run a new 12/2 cable from the original location to the new location
- In the original location, connect the original black (hot) wire to two short black wires and the new 12/2 cable black wire
- In the original location, connect the original white (neutral) wire to two short white wires and the new 12/2 cable white wire
- In the original location, connect the original ground wire to two short bare wires and the new 12/2 cable ground wire
- Connect each receptacle in the original location (one old, one new) to a set of hot/neutral/ground. Do NOT remove the tabs on the sides of the receptacles.
- In the new location, connect hot/neutral/ground to the new receptacle

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest headache will be getting enough slack in the wire to wire the box. Otherwise it is pretty straightforward. White to white. Black to black. Green/bare to green/bare. The usual caveats about understanding WHY aplies. If you don’t know why it is that way then I don’t recommend that you try.